# MBProgressHUD not resetting

Tags: ios, mbprogresshud

I'm using MBProgressHUD in our teaching App, which is tab bar navigated.

The user will come from a tableview via Urban Airship's storefront directly to the UA detail view.
Once buy is clicked I bring on HUD with

```
 HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
 [self.view.window addSubview:HUD];
```

It is using the **showWhileExecuting** statement.

It goes through three while statements to change from "Connecting" to "Downloading" to "Unpacking".
All working perfectly OK.

Here comes the problem...
The second time I do this the label text will not change.  It is stuck on "Connecting".
I can see in the NSLog that it is going through the other loops.
On top of that, if I try to change the Mode, the app crashes.

This only happens the second time, and any subsequent uses.  If I kill the App everything works again for the first time.

Looks to me that MBProgressHUD doesn't get reset when it's finished.
(ARC is used in the project)

Anyone with a solution?
Thanks

**Edit:**

```
- (void)showWithLabelDeterminate 
{

    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    [self.view.window addSubview:HUD];


    HUD.delegate = self;
    HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Connecting","");
    HUD.detailsLabelText = @" ";
    HUD.minSize = CGSizeMake(145.f, 145.f);
    HUD.dimBackground = YES;

    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(lessonDownloadProgress) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
}


-(void)lessonDownloadProgress
{

    DataManager *sharedManager = [DataManager sharedManager];
    //  HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    HUD.labelText = nil;
    HUD.detailsLabelText = nil;

    while ([sharedManager.downHUD floatValue] == 0.0f) 
    { 
        [self parentViewController];
        NSLog(@"HUD lessonDownloadProgress: %f", HUD.progress);
        HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Connecting","");
        HUD.detailsLabelText = @" ";
        NSLog(@"Waiting for download to start");
        //  Wait for download to start
        usleep(80000);
    }

    // Switch to determinate mode     
    // HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate;
    HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"DownLoading","");
    HUD.progress = [sharedManager.downHUD floatValue];

    while (HUD.progress < 1.0f && [sharedManager.cleanedUp isEqualToString:@"No"])
    {
        //  [self parentViewController];
        HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Downloading","");
        NSLog(@"HUD lessonDownloadProgress: %f", HUD.progress);
        HUD.progress = [sharedManager.downHUD floatValue];                       
        NSString *percent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", HUD.progress/1*100];
        HUD.detailsLabelText = [percent stringByAppendingString:@"%"];
        usleep(50000);
    }

    //  Switch HUD while cleanUp
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;

    while ([sharedManager.cleanedUp isEqualToString:@"No"]) 
    {
        [self parentViewController];
        HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Unpacking","");
        HUD.detailsLabelText = @" ";
        //  wait for cleanup
        NSLog(@"Waiting for clean up");
        usleep(50000);
    }

    NSLog(@"++ Finished loops ++");
    NSLog(@"Finished HUD lessonDownloadProgress: %f", HUD.progress);

    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    [HUD removeFromSuperview];
    HUD.delegate = nil;

    [HUD release];
    HUD = nil;

}
```

Comment: Is `HUD` an ivar or local variable?

Comment: It's a local, I think...   MBProgressHUD = *HUD

Comment: Likely ARC is releasing your reference to the `MBProgressHUD` so that attempts to modify its subviews subsequently fail.

Comment: Actually ARC is off for this class. Is there something I can do?  I've tried all these;   `   [HUD removeFromSuperview];
    HUD.delegate = nil;
    
    [HUD release];
    HUD = nil;
`

Comment: OK, can we see more of the code, then?  e.g. where you have `showWhileExecuting` and some snippets of the `while` statements to which you allude.

Comment: @alan duncan  I have edited into the main question. Would really appreciate any help as I'm totally stuck.

Comment: let me ask just one more question.  In your class interface, you have an ivar `MBProgress *HUD` declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot spot the issue in the code you posted; but some refactoring might help.

Rather than polling the `DataManager` you could use KVO to observe properties on the `DataManager` and respond to those changes.  *("Don't call us; we'll call you.)*  So here's a suggested approach if you want.

Your class interface:

```
@interface YourClass : UIViewController    // or whatever your superclass is...
{
    MBProgressHUD *_hud;
    DataManager *_dataManager;

    //  your other ivars
}
@end
```

And in your implementation file...

```
@interface YourClass()
@property (nonatomic, retain) DataManager dataManager;
@end
```

Above I've declared your dataManager as a property so that we can observe it.

To start the download process we now have a method `downloadLesson`:

```
- (void)downloadLesson;
{
    //  show HUD and retain it (showHUDAddedTo:animated: returns autoreleased object)
    MBProgressHUD *HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES] retain];

    //  observe properties on the dataManager
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dataManager.progress" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dataManager.cleanedUp" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dataManager.downHUD" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

    //  begin your download here...

    HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Connecting", "");
    HUD.detailsLabelText = @" ";
    HUD.progress = self.dataManager.downHUD;
}
```

Now use KVO to update the appearance of the HUD:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context;
{
    if( [keyPath isEqualToString:@"dataManager.cleanedUp"] )
    {
        if( [[[self dataManager] cleanedUp] isEqualToString:@"Yes"] )
        {
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] animated:YES];
            [HUD release];  HUD = nil;
            [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dataManager.progress"];
            [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dataManager.cleanedUp"];
            [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dataManager.downHUD"];
        }
    }
    if( [keyPath isEqualToString:@"dataManager.downHUD"] )
    {
        //  if the data manager updates progress, update our HUD
        HUD.progress = self.dataManager.downHUD;
        if( self.dataManager.downHUD == 0.0 )
            //  no progress; we're just connecting
            HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Connecting", "");
        else if( self.dataManager.downHUD < 1.0 )
        {
            //  progress >0.0 and < 1.0; we're downloading
            HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Downloading", "");
            NSString *percent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%%", HUD.progress/1*100];
            HUD.detailsLabelText = percent;
        }
        else
        {
            //  progress == 1.0, but we haven't cleaned up, so unpacking
            if( [[[self dataManager] cleanedUp] isEqualToString:@"No"] )
            {
                HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Unpacking","");
                HUD.detailLabelsText = @" ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use notifications to do the updates, wherein the `DataManager` posts `NSNotification`s for which your view controller is registered.  Or, if you were open to refactoring the `DataManager` you could use blocks to do the updates.  All of these solutions avoid having to explicitly block your thread to poll the `DataManager`.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement the delegate method?

```
- (void)hudWasHidden:(MBProgressHUD *)hud {
    // Remove HUD from screen when the HUD was hidded
    [HUD removeFromSuperview];
    HUD = nil;
}
```

Comment: Cheers, managed to kill it. It was actually an old bit of code left in calling the HUD.  Phew!!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the label is set up on init.Try this:

You should just add this method to the header file of MBProgressHud:

```
+ (MB_INSTANCETYPE)showHUDAddedTo:(UIView *)view withText:(NSString *)text;
```

And implement it in the .m file as follows:

```
+ (MB_INSTANCETYPE)showHUDAddedTo:(UIView *)view withText:(NSString *)text
{
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [[self alloc] initWithView:view];
    hud.labelText = text;
    [view addSubview:hud];
    [hud show:YES];
    return MB_AUTORELEASE(hud);
}
```

and call it wherever you want like:

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view withText:@"Loading..."];
```